Escape character for Databricks Custom Bundle Template
I need to deploy the string ${{ parameters.bundleTarget }} in my azure.yml.tmpl file, because that's how Azure Pipeline replaces variables.
However, the patter for replacement is the same for databricks custom bundles. So when I run databricks bundle init my-custom-bundle it tries to replace parameters.bundleTarget and gets an error because it does not exists in databricks bundles as it is a variable from Azure.
How can I use a scape character or pattern so I can deploy the ${{ parameters.bundleTarget }} as is, not making the substitution in the bundle creation?
I tried many things, like:

$\{{ parameters.bundleTarget }}\
{{%raw}}${{ parameters.bundleTarget }}{{%endraw}}
{{ '${{ parameters.bundleTarget }}' }}

none of them worked.

Can you elaborate more on how you use this custom variable? Where in databricks.yml do you use it? I don't understand how/when azure.yml.tmpl file is in conflict with the bundle config?!

Hi @Sergio, can you please share more details about how you replace variables in Azure Pipeline and use databricks custom bundles? If possible, please share your YAML and let us know what is running in the pipeline.


I need to deploy the string ${{ parameters.bundleTarget }} in my azure.yml.tmpl file, because that's how Azure Pipeline replaces variables.

In Azure DevOps pipeline, you can use replacetokens@6 task to replace the value in a file with different Token pattern.
My test steps:

Install extension Replace Tokens to the organization.

In the repo, I have a file named azure.yml.tmpl in the root folder. It contains the #{ bundleTarget }# I want to replace. So, I should have a variable named bundleTarget in my pipeline.

I use the #{ }# as Token pattern here. You can choose different pattern or use your custom one.


Use the following YAML to replace the bundleTarget. The variable bundleTarget is defined from the parameter value.


parameters:
- name: bundleTarget 
  type: string 
  default: myTarget
variables:
- name : bundleTarget
  value : ${{ parameters.bundleTarget }}
steps:
- task: replacetokens@6
  inputs:
    sources: 'azure.yml.tmpl'
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)



Run the pipeline with the bundleTarget value you want:


Check the replaced file in the published artifact:



